# setRegion() doesn't work if I instantiate a VC directly, but does work if I get to the VC via segue Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm experimenting a weird (in my opinion) change in behaviour of a function depending on how I get to the VC that contains it.
When user taps on a remote notification action the app goes from background to foreground,go to `NewMapViewController`, load up a route, display it as a `MKPolyline` and set the region based on the `MKPolyline` `MapRect`. Now the problem I'm facing is that `setRegion()` doesn't work depending on how I get to `NewMapViewController`. If in the action I instantiate the main `UINavigationController` and get to `NewMapController` via a segue than `setRegion` in `displayRoute()` works as expected but I see the `loginVC` before showing it. So not to show `loginVC` I instead instantiate `NewMapViewController` directly, but doing so `setRegion` in `displayRoute()` does not zoom on the `MKPolyline` anymore. Why can this be happening?
At first I thought that `configureMap`( centers map on user location ) was being called but no, all the prints show that when `NewMapViewController` gets loaded with that counter at 1, it never gets called.
I tried using `setVisibleMapRect()` instead of `setRegion()` but it made no difference. Is it a known bug? Is there any other way to get to `newMapViewController` that I should try? As always many thanks for your time and help.

Update:

After a few tries I decided to call `checkAlerts()` directly from the action body instead that from `viewWillApper()` counter check. That led to a nil error when adding the `MKPolyline` in `displayRoute()`. Searching a bit I found out that it is a thread problem, so by adding it in a  `DispatchQueue.main.async` queue it all worked again as expected.
It works whether I call `checkAlerts()` from the action body or from `viewWillApper()` counter check.
It seems that when I instantiate the `UINavigationController` and go to `NewMApController`via a segue it has the time to load the route and calculate the polyline, but when instantiating directly `NewMapController` does not. I'd like to understand it a bit better, does this make sense to you ?

This is the action:

```
case Id.checkActionIdentifier:
            print("Check tapped")
            let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
            if let routeToCheck = userInfo[NSLocalizedString("Route", comment: "")] as? String {
                RoutesArray.routeName = routeToCheck
//                print("rotta is: \(routeToCheck)")
            }
//            let content = response.notification.request.content
//            print(" Body \(content.body)")
//            print(" Title \(content.title)")
            NewMapViewController.routeCheckCounter = 1

            //  Goes to NewMapViewController but showing the loginVc first
//            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//            let initialViewController : UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
//            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
//            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
//            let vc = initialViewController.viewControllers[0]
//            vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "alertToMapSegue", sender: nil)

            // setRegion in displayRoute() not working ???
            if let navigationVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
                let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let newMapVC = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewMapViewController") as! NewMapViewController
                navigationVC.pushViewController(newMapVC, animated: true)
            }
```

and this is the function that displays the `MKPolyline`:

```
func displayRoute() {
        print("displayRoute called")
        var coordinateArray: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        for point in MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray {
            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point.coordinate.latitude, longitude: point.coordinate.longitude)
            coordinateArray.append(location)
        }
        // tracked CLLocations route
        routePolyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: coordinateArray, count: coordinateArray.count)
        mapView.add(routePolyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
        let startRouteAnnotation: RouteAnnotation = RouteAnnotation(title: "Route Start", coordinate: MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.first!.coordinate)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(startRouteAnnotation)

        let endRouteAnnotation = RouteAnnotation(title: "Route End", coordinate: MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.last!.coordinate)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(endRouteAnnotation)

        print("MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.count is: \(MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.count)")


        // full display
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(routePolyline!.boundingMapRect)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        // padded in
//        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(padMapRect(rect: routePolyline.boundingMapRect)), animated: true)
    }
```

this is how I get to call the function at `viewWillAppear()` :
(`checkAlerts()` is than calling `displayRoute()`.

```
// if loading vc from an scheduled alert check notification
        print(" CheckCounter is: \(NewMapViewController.routeCheckCounter ?? 0)")
        if NewMapViewController.routeCheckCounter ?? 0 > 0 {
            print("checkAlerts called in viewDidLoad")
            // load the route and call displayRoute()
            checkAlerts()
        } else {
            // just center map on user location
            configureMap()
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the tries described in the update part of my question here is the modified function that works just as expected:

```
func displayRoute() {
        print("displayRoute called")
        var coordinateArray: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        for point in MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray {
            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point.coordinate.latitude, longitude: point.coordinate.longitude)
            coordinateArray.append(location)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // tracked CLLocations route
        self.routePolyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: coordinateArray, count: coordinateArray.count)
        self.mapView.add(self.routePolyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)

        let startRouteAnnotation: RouteAnnotation = RouteAnnotation(title: "Route Start", coordinate: MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.first!.coordinate)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(startRouteAnnotation)

        let endRouteAnnotation = RouteAnnotation(title: "Route End", coordinate: MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.last!.coordinate)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(endRouteAnnotation)

        print("MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.count is: \(MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.count)")
//        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(padMapRect(rect: routePolyline.boundingMapRect)), animated: true)

        self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(self.padMapRect(rect: self.routePolyline.boundingMapRect), animated: true)
        }
    }
```